# Rails: content submitted using ckeditor is displayed with html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor

I have text field where user would be writing recipe of food item. For formatting of text, I just install ckeditor.

Added gem "ckeditor" in gemfile and executed this:

```
   rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip
```

as given in github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.

Then i updated my recipe text area to:

```
   <%= f.cktext_area :recipe, :size => 5, :id => "field-area5", :ckeditor => {:language => "us"}  %>
```

It displays all formatting tools and formats text properly. But when i submit the content and display the output using,

```
   <%= @product.recipe %>
```

it displays with HTML tags instead of the way i formatted. e.g.

```
  <p><strong>Recipe</strong></p> <h1><span style="font-family:georgia,serif"><em>i dont know anything</em></span></h1>
```

Can anybody help why this is happening? How to display formatted content? Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

`<%= raw(@product.recipe) %>`

Take a look here for further info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw

Comment: it is working! but the doc you shared says "This is not recommended if the data is coming from the user’s input." As the data i am displaying is coming from user. so would using "raw" is good way?

Comment: yey! I think you need to do two things. First you need to sanitize all user input before you save it to your database. Rails has a helper to do this called `sanitize` (docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) OR you can use something like the "sanitize" gem: https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize   I would suggest you go with the gem and check out the example on the docs.   Secondly once you have the sanitized/clean html then it should be safe to use `raw()` when emitting it back out in the view!

Comment: not getting how to use sanitize gem. You mean, it should be <%= sanitize.clean(@product.recipe) %> instead of <%= raw(@product.recipe) %> after installing gem? or <%= sanitize @product.recipe %> without gem.

Comment: try `<%= @product.recipe.to_s.html_safe %>`

Comment: `html_safe` is just as bad as using `raw`.

The problem in question has to do with Cross Site Scripting. Ckeditor includes styles and html tags, for those to appear, you need to render the content unescaped. However, you need to ensure that the content does not include dangerous content. Dangerous content such as `'onclick='` or links that download and install malware, other things. That's where `sanitize` comes in. You can strip certain tags and tag attributes using the sanitize helper method. The result is a `SafeBuffer` which should render without the need for `raw` or `html_safe`