# How to remove format use ckeditor-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using in my project in ruby on rails the gems ckeditor-rails
I use this in a text area in a form

```
f.text_area :description, :class=>'ckeditor' ,:cols=>"25", :rows=>"5"
```

But the problem is that when I saw in the show view I see something like that...

text here ..

and if I used any  list or  icon  I see

.... or , how to format the content of the text_area to don't see all of this anymore

any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
description= raw truncate(idea.description, :length=>40)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458401/rails-content-submitted-using-ckeditor-is-displayed-with-html-tags) are more info